# Return without double-space at the end with Visual Studio Code markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often write markdown-style documents for GitHub with VS Code.
When I preview it, it breaks lines only when I place 2 spaces at the end.
But is there any way to add a line break with simple return?

I know this is not a standard behaviour of traditional markdown,
but since GitHub supports simple return, I also want to have it locally.
(Otherwise, the sentences I see on VS Code preview and GitHub differs a lot...)